# set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE) doesn't work in cmake with SFML 2.5.1 on Debian 10 Buster

Tags: linux, cmake, sfml

I installed SFML with the command "apt install libsfml-dev".

I can link it in cmake discribed like in this post "https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24070.0" and everything works pretty fine.

But if I add set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE) to my cmake file to link sfml static I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake:139 (message):
  Requested SFML configuration (Static) was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake

  but it set SFML_FOUND to FALSE so package "SFML" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.
```

I recognized that the SFMLConfig.cmake file wants to access a SFMLStaticTargets.cmake file in line 110, if I set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE).

But my /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SFML folder just contains the following files for Shared linking:

- SFMLConfig.cmake
- SFMLConfigDependencies.cmake
- SFMLConfigVersion.cmake
- SFMLSharedTargets.cmake
- SFMLSharedTargets-none.cmake

In sfml version I can download here "https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/" I can also just find these files in the lib/cmake/SFML folder, but a SFMLSharedTargets-release.cmake file instead of SFMLSharedTargets-none.cmake.

What can I do to static link sfml 2.5.1 in cmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the sfml Forum!

> You have to recompile SFML, because pre-built packages for Linux don't
>   contain static libraries.

https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=26837

Answer (score 0):

The error you got comes from [`SFMLConfigDependencies.cmake`](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/cmake/SFMLConfigDependencies.cmake.in#L83), more specifically the last few lines.
The `sfml_bind_dependency` macro searches your system for `libXXX.so`, where `XXX` is one of the `SEARCH_NAMES`.

I think it suffices to install the `-dev` packages of the missing dependencies as follows:

```
apt install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev libxcb-image0-dev
```

Comment: Thank you. I get rid of the line
`SFML found but some of its dependencies are missing ( xcb-image FreeType libjpeg)`

But the rest didn't change. Still the same Error.